# Xcode: Swift - Table Cell not showing all text

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My cells are getting the text fine, but they aren't showing all the text.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM4c3.png

Here is the code for my table view controller:

```
class ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var mapItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return mapItems.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultsTableCell

    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    let row = indexPath.row
    let item = mapItems[row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
    cell.phoneLabel.text = item.phoneNumber
    return cell
}
```

}

I've searched around to see if I have a character limit set, but can't seem to find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your labels longer.

Comment: Is your UILabel wide enough?

Comment: Wow, what a stupid mistake on my end. Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `UILabels` aren't wide enough. If you make them wider, (or apply auto layout on all 4 sides, well... that gets more complicating,) then it should work fine.

Hope this helps!!